# Drupal 8 theme styling not linking to webpage

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-8

The theme works but none of the CSS is being applied. Even in the developer console in Firefox, it does not appear to be linked up to the page. I have manually applied the CSS through the developer console in Firefox just to confirm it works and it does.

To be clear, I have cleared the cache after any changes are made to the theme's files as well as reloaded the webpage. I have also tried different base themes but still get the same result. The theme is installed as the default theme and appears to be working, aside from CSS, as the block layout is correct for the items on the page.

I feel like the problem has something to do with linking the CSS to the page but I have tried everything from renaming the files to removing my custom CSS altogether and nothing has working so far.

---

My directory structure is as follows:

```
- themes
  - learn
     learn.info.yml
     learn.libraries.yml
     - css
        style.css  
     - templates
        html.html.twig
        page.html.twig
```

---

Below is my code for each file.

learn.info.yml

```
name: learn
type: theme
Description: "A theme to learn on"
package: custom
core: 8.x
libraries:
  - 'learn/global-css'

base theme: stable
regions:
  headline: headline
  header: header
  content: content
  sidebar_top: sidebar_top
  sidebar_bottom: sidebar_bottom
  footer: Footer
```

---

learn.libraries.yml

```
#libraries file: learn.libraries.yml
global-css:
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
```

---

style.css

```
#headline {
  grid-area: headline;
  align-self: center;
}

#topbar {
  grid-area: header;
}

#main {
  grid-area: main;
}

#sidebar-top {
  grid-area: sidebar-top;
}

#sidebar-bottom {
  grid-area: sidebar-bottom;
}

#footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}


.container {
  font-family: Georgia, sans-serif;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas:
    ". headline headline ." 
    "header header header header"
    "main main main sidebar-top"
    "main main main sidebar-bottom"
    "footer footer footer footer";

}
```

---

page.html.twig

```
<div id="headline">
    {{ page.headline }}
</div>
<div id="topbar">
    {{ page.header }}
</div>
<div id="main">
    {{ page.content }}
</div>
<div id="sidebar-top">
  {{ page.sidebar_top}}
</div>
<div id="sidebar-bottom">
  {{ page.sidebar_bottom}}
</div>
<footer id="footer">
  <hr>
  {{ page.footer }}
</footer>
```

---

html.html.twig

```
<head>
  {{ head_title }}
</head>
<body>
  {{ page_top }}
  {{ page }}
  {{ page_bottom }}
</body
```

---

Source code for the webpage:

```
<script type="application/vnd.drupal-ajax" data-big-pipe-event="start"></script>

<script type="application/vnd.drupal-ajax" data-big-pipe-event="stop"></script>
</body><head>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="toolbar-administration" role="group" aria-label="Site administration toolbar" class="toolbar">
  <nav id="toolbar-bar" role="navigation" aria-label="Toolbar items" class="toolbar-bar clearfix">
    <h2 class="visually-hidden">Toolbar items</h2>
                <div class="home-toolbar-tab toolbar-tab">
        <a href="/" title="Return to site content" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-escape-admin toolbar-item" data-toolbar-escape-admin>Back to site</a>
        <div><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation"></nav></div>      </div>
                <div class="toolbar-tab">
        <a href="/admin" title="Admin menu" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-menu trigger toolbar-item" data-drupal-subtrees="" id="toolbar-item-administration" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-administration-tray" aria-owns="toolbar-item-administration-tray" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Manage</a>
        <div id="toolbar-item-administration-tray" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-administration-tray" class="toolbar-tray"><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation" aria-label="Administration menu"><h3 class="toolbar-tray-name visually-hidden">Administration menu</h3><div class="toolbar-menu-administration"><ul class="toolbar-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item--collapsed"><a href="/admin/content" title="Find and manage content." id="toolbar-link-system-admin_content" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-admin-content" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/content">Content</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item--collapsed"><a href="/admin/structure" title="Administer blocks, content types, menus, etc." id="toolbar-link-system-admin_structure" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-admin-structure" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/structure">Structure</a></li><li class="menu-item"><a href="/admin/appearance" title="Select and configure themes." id="toolbar-link-system-themes_page" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-themes-page" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/appearance">Appearance</a></li><li class="menu-item"><a href="/admin/modules" title="Add and enable modules to extend site functionality." id="toolbar-link-system-modules_list" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-modules-list" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/modules">Extend</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item--collapsed"><a href="/admin/config" title="Administer settings." id="toolbar-link-system-admin_config" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-admin-config" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/config">Configuration</a></li><li class="menu-item"><a href="/admin/people" title="Manage user accounts, roles, and permissions." id="toolbar-link-entity-user-collection" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-entity-user-collection" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/people">People</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item--collapsed"><a href="/admin/reports" title="View reports, updates, and errors." id="toolbar-link-system-admin_reports" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-system-admin-reports" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/reports">Reports</a></li><li class="menu-item"><a href="/admin/help" title="Reference for usage, configuration, and modules." id="toolbar-link-help-main" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-help-main" data-drupal-link-system-path="admin/help">Help</a></li></ul></div></nav></div>      </div>
                <div class="toolbar-tab">
        <a href="/admin/config/user-interface/shortcut" title="Shortcuts" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-shortcut trigger toolbar-item" id="toolbar-item-shortcuts" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-shortcuts-tray" aria-owns="toolbar-item-shortcuts-tray" role="button" aria-pressed="false">Shortcuts</a>
        <div id="toolbar-item-shortcuts-tray" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-shortcuts-tray" class="toolbar-tray"><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation" aria-label="User-defined shortcuts"><h3 class="toolbar-tray-name visually-hidden">User-defined shortcuts</h3><ul class="toolbar-menu"><li><a href="/node/add">Add content</a></li><li><a href="/admin/content">All content</a></li></ul><a href="/admin/config/user-interface/shortcut/manage/default/customize" class="edit-shortcuts">Edit shortcuts</a></nav></div>      </div>
                <div class="hidden contextual-toolbar-tab toolbar-tab">
        <button class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-edit toolbar-item" aria-pressed="false" type="button">Edit</button>

        <div><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation"></nav></div>      </div>
                <div class="tour-toolbar-tab hidden toolbar-tab" id="toolbar-tab-tour">
        <button class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-help toolbar-item" aria-pressed="false" type="button">Tour</button>

        <div><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation"></nav></div>      </div>
                <div class="toolbar-tab">
        <a href="/user" title="My account" class="toolbar-icon toolbar-icon-user trigger toolbar-item" id="toolbar-item-user" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-user-tray" aria-owns="toolbar-item-user-tray" role="button" aria-pressed="false"><span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="callback=user.toolbar_link_builder%3ArenderDisplayName&amp;&amp;token=-MH2NzEnTzbzMk0ZGfGgoiw7G3j_-Q1ILWBRVhIOKLI"></span></a>
        <div id="toolbar-item-user-tray" data-toolbar-tray="toolbar-item-user-tray" class="toolbar-tray"><nav class="toolbar-lining clearfix" role="navigation" aria-label="User account actions"><h3 class="toolbar-tray-name visually-hidden">User account actions</h3><span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="callback=user.toolbar_link_builder%3ArenderToolbarLinks&amp;&amp;token=xssKdKFVFD7N0FUPPcC1C7LrqMHpQFVzUhrI4cOeEgs"></span></nav></div>      </div>
      </nav>

</div>

    <div class="dialog-off-canvas-main-canvas" data-off-canvas-main-canvas>
    <div class="container">
  <div id="headline">
        <div class="region region-headline">
    <div id="block-learn-branding" class="contextual-region block block-system block-system-branding-block">

    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_branding:langcode=en"></div>
        <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home" class="site-logo">
      <img src="/themes/learn/logo.svg" alt="Home" />
    </a>
        <div class="site-name">
      <a href="/" title="Home" rel="home">Testing</a>
    </div>
    </div>
<div id="block-learn-page-title" class="contextual-region block block-core block-page-title-block">

    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_page_title:langcode=en"></div>

  <h1 class="js-quickedit-page-title page-title">Welcome to Testing</h1>


  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="topbar">
        <div class="region region-header">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-learn-main-menu-menu" id="block-learn-main-menu" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--main">

  <h2 class="visually-hidden" id="block-learn-main-menu-menu">Main navigation</h2>
  <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_main_menu:langcode=en|menu:menu=main:langcode=en"></div>


              <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/" data-drupal-link-system-path="&lt;front&gt;">Home</a>
              </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/help" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/2">help</a>
              </li>
        </ul>



  </nav>

  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="main">
        <div class="region region-content">
    <div id="block-learn-content" class="block block-system block-system-main-block">


      <div class="views-element-container contextual-region"><div class="contextual-region view view-frontpage view-id-frontpage view-display-id-page_1 js-view-dom-id-f8689dcf3daa7451b89b435b7b92fa14a06712a07116849e050187e0b48ed7e5">

    <div data-contextual-id="entity.view.edit_form:view=frontpage:location=page&amp;name=frontpage&amp;display_id=page_1&amp;langcode=en"></div>

      <div class="view-empty">
      No front page content has been created yet.<br />Follow the <a target="_blank" href="https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/index.html">User Guide</a> to start building your site.<ul class="links"><li><a href="/node/add">Add content</a></li></ul>
    </div>


              <div class="feed-icons">
      <a href="http://dtheme.dd:8083/rss.xml" class="feed-icon">
  Subscribe to 
</a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-top">
      <div class="region region-sidebar-top">
    <div class="search-block-form contextual-region block block-search container-inline" data-drupal-selector="search-block-form" id="block-learn-search" role="search">

      <h2>Search</h2>
    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_search:langcode=en"></div>
      <form action="/search/node" method="get" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-search form-type-search js-form-item-keys form-item-keys form-no-label">
      <label for="edit-keys" class="visually-hidden">Search</label>
        <input title="Enter the terms you wish to search for." data-drupal-selector="edit-keys" type="search" id="edit-keys" name="keys" value="" size="15" maxlength="128" class="form-search" />

        </div>
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper" id="edit-actions"><input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit" type="submit" id="edit-submit" value="Search" class="button js-form-submit form-submit" />
</div>

</form>

  </div>
<div class="views-element-container contextual-region block block-views block-views-blockposts-block-1" id="block-views-block-posts-block-1">

      <h2>Posts</h2>
    <div data-contextual-id="block:block=views_block__posts_block_1:langcode=en|entity.view.edit_form:view=posts:location=block&amp;name=posts&amp;display_id=block_1&amp;langcode=en"></div>
      <div><div class="contextual-region view view-posts view-id-posts view-display-id-block_1 js-view-dom-id-356becb689640db1e1b061ec9a73f60e2f550bd53a175c6111a64f9caa3d1be2">

    <div data-contextual-id="entity.view.edit_form:view=posts:location=block&amp;name=posts&amp;display_id=block_1&amp;langcode=en"></div>

      <div class="view-content">
      <div class="item-list">

  <ul>

          <li>
<article data-history-node-id="2" data-quickedit-entity-id="node/2" role="article" class="contextual-region node node--type-page node--view-mode-teaser" about="/help" typeof="schema:WebPage">


      <h2>
      <a href="/help" rel="bookmark"><span property="schema:name" data-quickedit-field-id="node/2/title/en/teaser" class="field field--name-title field--type-string field--label-hidden">help</span>
</a>
    </h2>
    <div data-contextual-id="node:node=2:changed=1533146323&amp;langcode=en"></div>  <span property="schema:name" content="help" class="rdf-meta hidden"></span>



  <div class="node__content">

            <div property="schema:text" data-quickedit-field-id="node/2/body/en/teaser" class="clearfix text-formatted field field--name-body field--type-text-with-summary field--label-hidden field__item"><p>This theme isnt working...</p></div>
        <div class="node__links">
    <ul class="links inline"><li class="node-readmore"><a href="/help" rel="tag" title="help" hreflang="en">Read more<span class="visually-hidden"> about help</span></a></li></ul>  </div>

  </div>

</article>
</li>

  </ul>

</div>

    </div>

          </div>
</div>

  </div>

  </div>

  </div>
  <div id="sidebar-bottom">
      <div class="region region-sidebar-bottom">
    <span data-big-pipe-placeholder-id="callback=Drupal%5CCore%5CRender%5CElement%5CStatusMessages%3A%3ArenderMessages&amp;args%5B0%5D&amp;token=_HAdUpwWmet0TOTe2PSiJuMntExoshbm1kh2wQzzzAA"></span>
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-learn-tools-menu" id="block-learn-tools" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--tools">

  <h2 id="block-learn-tools-menu">Tools</h2>
  <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_tools:langcode=en|menu:menu=tools:langcode=en"></div>


              <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/node/add" data-drupal-link-system-path="node/add">Add content</a>
              </li>
        </ul>



  </nav>
<nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-learn-account-menu-menu" id="block-learn-account-menu" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--account">

  <h2 class="visually-hidden" id="block-learn-account-menu-menu">User account menu</h2>
  <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_account_menu:langcode=en|menu:menu=account:langcode=en"></div>


              <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/user" data-drupal-link-system-path="user">My account</a>
              </li>
                <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/user/logout" data-drupal-link-system-path="user/logout">Log out</a>
              </li>
        </ul>



  </nav>

  </div>

  </div>
  <footer id="footer">
    <hr>
      <div class="region region-footer">
    <nav role="navigation" aria-labelledby="block-learn-footer-menu" id="block-learn-footer" class="contextual-region block block-menu navigation menu--footer">

  <h2 class="visually-hidden" id="block-learn-footer-menu">Footer menu</h2>
  <div data-contextual-id="block:block=learn_footer:langcode=en|menu:menu=footer:langcode=en"></div>


              <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="menu-item">
        <a href="/contact" data-drupal-link-system-path="contact">Contact</a>
              </li>
        </ul>



  </nav>

  </div>

  </footer>
</div>
  </div>


</body>
```

Sorry this is so long, just trying to be thorough.

**EDIT:**

While the answer *is* correct, I just wanted to make sure to clarify that

```
<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
```

is the exact line that fixed the CSS linking issue.

Comment: have you selected your theme as the default theme?

Comment: Yes. It is installed and the default theme. I know he theme is working, aside from the CSS, because the block layout is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your libraries.yml you have `css/custom.css: {}`,
but the file name is `style.css`

Change `css/custom.css: {}` to `css/style.css: {}` in your "learn.libraries.yml" file.

**EDIT:**

You need to include `{{ page_top }}` and `{{ page_bottom }}` in your html.html.twig. These include things like script tags.

eg:

```
<body>
<head>
</head>
{{ page_top }}
<div id="page" class="container">
  {{ page }}
</div>
{{ page_bottom }}
</body>
```

And, you should probably move the `<div id="page" class="container">` to the page template

**EDIT 2.**

As you are using "stable" as your base theme, the easiest way to find the source of your problem will be to copy the "stable" theme template, then edit them as necessary.

Looking at the "stable" themes html.html.twig, posted below, you are also missing a few other things that seem like they would be needed.

Of particular note are the css-placeholder tags which it seems would be particularly relevant in your case.

the stable themes html.html.twig looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html{{ html_attributes }}>
  <head>
    <head-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <title>{{ head_title|safe_join(' | ') }}</title>
    <css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
    <js-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </head>
  <body{{ attributes }}>
    {#
      Keyboard navigation/accessibility link to main content section in
      page.html.twig.
    #}
    <a href="#main-content" class="visually-hidden focusable">
      {{ 'Skip to main content'|t }}
    </a>
    {{ page_top }}
    {{ page }}
    {{ page_bottom }}
    <js-bottom-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry that’s a typo, I was testing different file names and must have copied the wrong code. In my code it’s style.css. I fixed it in he question.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn’t change much aside from the admin level content appearing. There is still no style sheet attached to the page.

Comment: That works! I did some testing and it looks like `<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` is the required line to get the CSS to link up correctly. Thanks!